# oracle sql: insert long text but receive SP2-0778: Script filename and arguments too long

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I've a SQL script that is called and containing among others follwoing line:

```
@@./sql/common/scripts/LX2/InsertOrUpdateDefaultValuesLongVersions.sql 'typeinterface' 'en' 'ABCD.translation.SET0136.descriptions' 'Some Long text .............. ....... ....... .......... ........... .......... ....... .......... ............. ......... ......... ............. ......... ............. .....!' 'Some Longer Text .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......... .............. ....... ....... .......!';
-- shorter version (arg4 and arg5 are long texts)
@@./sql/common/scripts/LX2/InsertOrUpdateDefaultValuesLongVersions.sql '<arg1>' '<arg2>' '<arg3>' '<arg4>' '<arg5>';
```

When executing it I get following error:

> SP2-0778: Script filename and arguments too long

So it seems that file name & path together witht he arguments is to long.
But I can't find out what would be the limit?

`InsertOrUpdateDefaultValuesLongVersions.sql` is simply inserting the arguments to a table (based on the first arguments).
It seems that the value is to long to be inserted at once, but how would I insert these long texts into the database?

Comment: Put the values in a file and load them through SQL* Loader

Comment: Maybe this link can throw some insight, it talks about acceptable lengths of various attributes for SQL Plus - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/apa.htm#SQPUG141

Answer (score 1):

You have indeed hit an SQLPlus limit.

From [the Oracle doc on error SP2-0778](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch13.htm) :

> **Cause**: The combined length of the script filename and script arguments is too long for SQL*Plus.
>
> **Action**: Reduce the length of the script name and path. Reduce the number and/or size of the script arguments.

This [other Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a82950/appc.htm) states that :

- Max filename length is platform dependant
- Max command-line length is 2500 characters

You probably hit the second limit. There does not seem to exist a workaround, you would need do somehow decrease the length of your command line.

Another possible option is not to use SQLPlus ; you could consider using SQLLoader for example (you would need to put your arguments in a file).

Alternatively, as commented by @APC, there is [a new Oracle client called sqlcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html) which seemingly does not have this limitation.

Comment: Alternatively there is the new Oracle `sqlcl` client which I thing doesn't have this limitation (don't have an instance to hand, so can't test). [Find out more](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html)

Comment: Thanks for information @APC, added that to my answer.

Comment: please verify before including in you answer :)